# ¿Qué sucede al intentar cambiarse el nick y ponerse un diamante al final simulando ser moderador?

Tags: soporte, moderadores, usuarios

Estuve mirando una lista de usuarios y como bien se sabe, los moderadores tienen un diamante al final. Por esto me surgió una curiosidad.

Entonces pienso, pero es solo un caracter muy simple, y me surge la pregunta, ya que los moderadores tienen ese caracter al final, ¿Está permitido cambiarse el nick usando ese caracter? y si es así, ¿El sistema permite agregarlo al final del nick simulando ser un moderador?

¿Existen caracteres unicode similares al diamante que puedan ser usados en el nick? ¿o directamente no se permiten usar caracteres especiales?

No me animo a intentarlo por el momento, así que preferiría tener una respuesta sobre este asunto.

Comment: Hey Emiliano ¿Querías volver ser moderador?

Comment: @Jorgesys Andaba algo ocupado pero últimamente aprendí muchas cosas sobre la moderación, en estos últimos tiempos leo bastante aquí en _Meta_ sobre varias cuestiones. Quizás me presente la próxima vez, veremos porque es bastante la presión y responsabilidad. Pero además me gana la distracción porque juego bastante al solitario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se quita automáticamente:

> The user name field already has a filter that removes the Unicode ♦ character (and some look-a-likes) used to identify moderators. Users are not allowed to spoof this as part of their username.

De [Is making yourself appear (at first glance) to be a moderator acceptable behaviour?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230643/209901)

Answer (score 2):

Encontré este emoji ♦️. Si intento ponerlo en el nick sale un error.

Tratando de cambiar el nombre a:

> ArtEze ♦️

Aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> ¡Uy! Se produjo un problema al actualizar tu perfil:
>
> - El nombre para mostrar solo puede contener letras, dígitos, espacios, apóstrofos o guiones y debe comenzar con una letra o un dígito.